# Rheostat circuit help

Tags: resistance, potentiometer, rheostat

How much can I actually vary with this rheostat and what resistance value should I make it to get precise control of the RPM of the motor- maybe control in +100RPM by varying resistance and then voltage gets effected?

Can someone explain how the varying works, is there a formula?

Motor: 4V, 3000RPM at 4V brushed ,
Battery: 4V
Rheostat: ?ohm

[image]

Comment: what does `precise control` mean?

Comment: Hi, control it so output RPM changes by 100rpm or around that?

Comment: Series resistance ;”(rheostat) will not allow you to control RPM in any way but for a fixed torque, including no torque. With varying torque (normal load), it will only make the RPM change due to torque even more pronounced.

Comment: Is this a brushed or brushless motor?

Comment: Brushed motor. I thought that by varying resistance, we could control voltage too?

Comment: No, you just form a very current dependent voltage divider. What you get is a throttle, but it won’t control RPM in the same manner as pressing the throttle on a car won’t give you constant speed, it will depend on going up or downhill. You’ll need a feedback mechanism in the same way as cruise control.